# How to configure Windows RDC to use 16-color mode?

Tags: windows-server-2008, rdp, rdc

I seriously need to minimize the "eye candy" traffic overhead and only leave the graphics quality enough to actually manage the server. I've like to switch to 16 or 256 color mode if possible but the lowest color depth offered by the client settings is 15-bit High Color. Is this possible to overcome?

The problem is that the app I need to configure on the server side is a stupid surveillance dashboard and it always displays 9 real time video streams all the time it is open (though I only need to adjust its settings) giving a pure zen training experience.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have found the answer myself, so sharing it for further reference of whoever may need it.

The solution is to open the `.rdp` file (`%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Default.rdp` by default) and edit (or add if missing) the following line:

```
session bpp:i:8
```

The number (8 in this case) sets the color resolution in bits per pixel. 8 (for 256 colors) is the lowest value available through manual editing (while the lowest value available through the RDC GUI is 15).

Other `.rdp` file commands can be found [here](https://helpforsure.wordpress.com/2011/01/23/rdp-settings-for-remote-desktop-connection-version-7%E2%80%8F/).

PS: I am also glad to mention that my practical problem (unintentional but unavoidable video streaming jamming the whole RDP channel) is solved completely! The thing works lightning-fast now. So the idea to lower the color depth was right what I needed.

Comment: Nice detective work, thanks for sharing the answer

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to have any effect when RDP'ing to Windows 10 clients...

Answer (score 2):

Not with a modern version of the MicroSoft Terminal Services Client, no.  The best you can do is head over to the Experience tab and select `Modem (56 Kbps)`, which should be more than sufficient.  (Note the `Persistent bitmap caching` option).

Of course, as this is rated for a 56 Kbps connection, I'd advise that if you need something less bandwidth intensive, your primary focus should be on upgrading your network capacity, because 56 Kbps hasn't been a normal amount of network bandwidth for a couple decades now.

[image]

Comment: Helps slightly (subjectively) but doesn't solve the problem. I am reading about the `.rdp` file format now, perhaps I could configure it manually. The problem is that the app I need to configure on the server side is a stupid surveillance dashboard and it always displays 9 video streams all the time it is open (though I only need to adjust its settings) giving a pure zen training experience...

Comment: @Ivan Ugh, developers.  Can you RDP in with an older version of the client?  Say, if you have a pre-SP3 XP disc lying around, fire up a VM from that and use the older version of the client that allows you to select the lower color depth values?

Answer (score 1):

Go the the Experience tab in the RDP client and set the connection speed to: Modem (56kbps).

Comment: It does not help to switch color depth below high-color.

Comment: I'm afraid that's as close as you're going to get.

Answer (score 0):

[Remote Desktop Connection Manager](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=44989), a free Microsoft tool that adds functionality to the Terminal Services Client, supports this option:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since Win8 and newer enforce high colour depth in RDP sessions, as a workaround, you can RDP in low colour to Win8/10/11 by jumping through a Win7 box.

Eg RDP to Win7 at low colour depth, then from Win7, RDP to the newer OS (Win10 in the pic, at colour depth 8):

[image]